# Programmatically creating two UIPickerViews but all values go to second

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am writing code to programmatically create a view.  In this view I am creating two UIPickerViews, however, as the title explains, when I go to populate the lists with data, all of the data goes into the second table, and none in the first.  I can see where exactly the problem is, but don't know how to fix it.  Here is the code with editing around non-related parts.

in the below section is where i create the pickerview.  Essentially I have a large list of data.  If i see any occurance of "RadioButton" I create a PickerView.  RadioButton can appear more than once and is where my issue lies.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++){  
 ...

 else if([input.controlTypeName compare:@"RadioButton"] == NSOrderedSame){
        [radioList addObject:input.sourceText]; 
        radioPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, y, 220, 200)];
        radioPicker.delegate = self;
        radioPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        [inputsView addSubview:radioPicker];
        y = y+220;

    }
```

the delegate methods are as follows..

```
       - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection
}

// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if([pickerView isEqual: radioPicker]){
    return [radioList count];
}




 // tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
   return 1;
}

 // tell the picker the title for a given component
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

  if([pickerView isEqual: radioPicker]){
    id myArrayElement = [radioList objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *title = myArrayElement; 
    NSLog(@"title to fill radio:%@", title); 
    return title;
  }


 }

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
int sectionWidth = 200;

   return sectionWidth;
 }
```

Essentially what seems to be happening is on the 2nd creation of the 'RadioButton' ListPicker, the first creation loses the tag 'radioPicker'  and the line

```
if([pickerView isEqual: radioPicker]){
```

fails.  So all of the data is pushed into the second(and latest) creation.  But I don't know how to have this not happen.  Any ideas would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd go with == rather than isEqual in this case, you want to check for pointer equality with your ivar. I can't see any code here where you create a second picker view?

Comment: A second picker view is created if a second instance of 'radiobutton' is found in the array of data.  it would use the exact same else if i quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a single instance variable, `radioPicker`. It's fine to have two `UIPickerView`s and be the delegate of both. However, you need to base the delegate methods on the passed-in value, not the (single) instance variable.

There's actually no need to have `radioPicker`. Once you send `addSubview:`, just autorelease the view (unless you're using ARC).

In order to distinguish the views, you might want to set the `tag` property, and use that in things like the `titleForRow:` delegate method.

Comment: I see exactly what you are saying about my single instance variable.  So my question is, how can I keep track of all the lists created?  is creating a local variable and just incrementing it one for every 'radiobutton' found.  then using that as a tag what you mean?

Comment: Right, something like `data[radioPicker.tag]` (assuming you set a unique tag when you create the `UIPickerView`). You don't need to keep track to get rid of them, the superview owns its child views.